# What is the impact of WAITFOR on other processes and transactions?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I try to find out the performance or internal implementation for WAITFOR in T-SQL, have gone through [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187331%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) and Stackoverflow and other sites without luck, here is my question

For below code, I want to delete the top 10,000 rows from table `DUMMY`. I want to make this delete job have the least performance impact on the database's other jobs as possible and give priority to others (if any). So I make it delete 100 rows at a time and do it 100 times with sleep time in two adjacent deletes.

Question:

1. During the `WAITFOR` blocking time, will this transaction consume CPU or just idle and waiting for kicked up by some event 1 second later?
2. During that 1 sec, if there are other transactions trying to `INSERT/UPDATE` on the `DUMMY` table, who gets priority?

Really appreciate your help or any insights for this

```
declare @cnt int 
set @cnt = 0
while @cnt < 100
begin
  delete top 100 from DUMMYTABLE where FOO = 'BAR'
  set @cnt = @cnt + 1
  waitfor delay '00:00:01'
end
```

Comment: For point 2, it depends on whether you've shown us the whole code - if the code is running inside a transaction, that changes everything

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for pointing out, it is not in a BEGIN TRAN ... COMMIT block, just tsql wrapped in perl.

Comment: If you really want to minimise impact, make sure there is an index on FOO

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- It does not consume any CPU
- Status = suspended

You can see this with 2 query windows:

```
SELECT @@SPID;
GO
WAITFOR DELAY '000:03:00'; -- three minutes
```

Then in the other

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses S WHERE S.spid = 53; -- replace 53
```

Note: SQL Server 2012 SP1 but AFAIK behaviour is the same

Point 2, sorry missed this

Another session will modify the table while the WAITFOR is running. It isn't a lock.

Comment: thank you gbn, your answer and experiment are so helpful! don't know we can do something like this before. thanks a lot!